# Не могу сделать POST запрос на сервер

Tags: javascript, post, express, mongoose, nodemon

### index.js

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const authRoutes = require('./routes/authRoutes');


const app = express();

const mongoUri = "mongodb+srv://admin:hereismypassword@cluster0.r8k2r.mongodb.net/trackDB?retryWrites=true&w=majority"

mongoose.connect(mongoUri, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology:true,
});

mongoose.connection.on("connected", () => {
   console.log("Connected to the mongo instance")
});

mongoose.connection.on("error", (err) => {
  console.error("Error connecting to mongo",)
});
```

### authRoutes

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.post("/sign", (req, res) => {
  res.send("You made a post request !");
});

module.exports = router;
```

### Postman err

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Error</title>
</head>

<body>
    <pre>Cannot POST /sign</pre>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Struggled and founded that missed in index.js some important part that makes usable my authRoutes.js file

```
app.use(authRoutes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Забыл сделать app.use(authRoutes);

Comment: Спасибо за дублирование моего ответа ...